# How to get a name of default browser using python

Tags: python

how do access default browser first 10 url histories in python?

```
from browser_history import get_history

outputs = get_history()

# his is a list of (datetime.datetime, url) tuples

his = outputs.histories[0:10]
for i in his:
    print(i)
print("history length",len(his))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you're looking for.

```
from browser_history import get_history

# Get the browser history from the get_history function
history = get_history().histories

# Create a new list to store the unique history
unique_history = []

# Iterate over the history list
for i in history:
    # Get the URL from the current history item
    url = i[1]
    
    # Check if the URL is already in the unique_history list
    if url in unique_history:
        # If it is, skip to the next iteration
        continue
    
    # If it's not, add it to the unique_history list
    unique_history.append(url)

# Print the last 10 elements of the unique_history list
print(unique_history[-10:])
```

Comment: It's good but i did not get current browser url history when browser opened,once closed browser after that i got it,is any solution to get current url when browser opened using python code?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to retrieve browser history from an active web-browser.

Comment: suppose if you know in future,please update,thanks